# Polar Decomposition: Approximation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

Polar Decomposition:
$$\forall A\in\mathcal{A}\exists V_\varepsilon\in\mathcal{A}:\quad A=V_\varepsilon|A|^{1-\varepsilon}\quad(\varepsilon>0)$$

How can I construct this?

Similar statement: [Wegge-Olsen, Exercise 1.A.c](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/k-theory-and-c-algebras-9780198596943?cc=us&lang=en&)

Comment: Are you Canadian ? So am I. I am also in Germany.

Comment: Haha, because of the flag? :D I'm a huge fan of the country. But sadly I only went once to Canada. Ah nice, which city are you in Germany?

Comment: Over the holidays I'm in Hamburg, but mostly I am in Berlin. Never been to Munich, I should visit it someday.

Comment: Ah nice what doing in Hamburg and Berlin, if I may ask? I currently live in Münster only for vacations going to Munich.

Comment: Since it requires some work I will not copy it, but you can find it in Prop. 2.13 here: https://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/hannes.thiel/teaching/CuScript-08.pdf

Comment: Also see Prop 1.4.5 in Pedersen's *$C^{\ast}$-algebras and their Automorphism groups*

Comment: @AndréS.: Oh true that we did in class.. :) But how do we argue that the resulting element indeed belongs to the algebra?

Comment: Apply the previous lemma (2.12) with $B: = B(H)$ and $v: = w$. Then $x = wa \in A$ and so $wf(a) \in A$ if $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @AndréS.: Got it thank you!! :D